# swift drag and drop functionality is not working properly

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift3

drag and drop functionality is not working properly the tasks are not proper drag and drop on particular position.

```
    private func addTaskData(document: [QueryDocumentSnapshot]) {
        allTasks.removeAll()
        for query in document {
            let aTask = Task()
            aTask.initWithDict(snapshot: query)
            self.allTasks.append(aTask)
                sortedArray = self.allTasks.sorted(by: { $0.scheduleDate.timeIntervalSince1970 > $1.scheduleDate.timeIntervalSince1970})
            for task in allTasks {
                if (currentTasks.contains(where: { $0.title == task.title }))
                {
                    print(task.title,"contain")
                }
                else
                {
                    if (sortedArray.contains(where: { $0.title == task.title }))
                    {
                        print(task.title,"contain")
                    }
                    else{
                        print(task.title,"not contain")
                        task.scheduleDate = Date()
                        sortedArray.insert(task, at: 0)
                    }
                  
                }
            }
            self.allTasks = sortedArray
        }
        for task in allTasks {
            if isPremium{
                if nextDateString == "12 AM" {
                    print("schedule date is past")
                    if task.isDone == false {
                        isDateUpdate = true
                        isUpdateingDateStatus = true
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                print("schedule date is current or future")
            }
        }
        updateSelectedTasks()
        taskTableView.reloadData()
    }
```

this moveRowAt function first time performing drag and drop functionality perfectly but the second time i am performing drag and drop it is not working.
i think this issue occurred because of improper assignment of schedule date like this, positions of tasks before drag and drop :
`Test 2 Test 1 Test 3 Test 4 Test 5`
and i have dragged and dropped 'Test 1' task it should be like this:
`Test 2 Test 3 Test 4 Test 1 Test 5`
but it shows tasks like this :
`Test 5 Test 1 Test 4 Test 3 Test 2`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
        // Update the model
        let movedTask = currentTasks.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
        currentTasks.insert(movedTask, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
        
        for (index, task) in currentTasks.enumerated() {
            let date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: index , to: Date())!
            task.scheduleDate = date
            db.collection(udid).document(task.id).updateData(["scheduleDate": date])
        }
        
        // Reload table data
        taskTableView.reloadData()
    }
```